# ASP.NET Core execute Linux shell command

Tags: asp.net, linux, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there any way to execute a linux shell command from within an ASP.NET Core application and return the value into a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best possibility currently seems to be to use the prerelease of `SSH.Net.Core` https://www.nuget.org/packages/SSH.Net.Core/0.9.1-rc

Comment: that presumes that you want to run it on some other machine than the one where you are running the ASP.NET Core application. :) This is not obvious from the question, even though it's a fairly reasonably assumption.