# how ASP.NET Core execute Linux shell command?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core web app on Linux. I want to execute shell commands and get result from commands.

Is there a way to execute a Linux shell command from within an ASP.NET Core application and return the value into a variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core execute Linux shell command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987760/asp-net-core-execute-linux-shell-command)

Comment: `Process.Execute`?

Answer (score 13):

```
string RunCommand(string command, string args)
{
    var process = new Process()
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = command,
            Arguments = args,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
        }
    };
    process.Start();
    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(error)) { return output; }
    else { return error; }
}

// ...

string rez = RunCommand("date", string.Empty);
```

I would also add some way to tell if the string returned is an error or just a "normal" output (return `Tuple<bool, string>` or throw exception with `error` as a message).