# Exectute a Linux Shell command from ASP.NET Core 3 app

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-mvc, shell, asp.net-core

**My question** is literally, how do I execute a Shell command from my application. There is a similar [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764172/how-asp-net-core-execute-linux-shell-command/50898285), but that shows how to execute a script file and requires the path to that file.

```
var process = new Process()
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = command, // Path required here
            Arguments = args,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
        }
    };
process.Start();
```

**Why I want to pass the command as a string?**

Because I want to interpolate it. Otherwise, I would have to create a script, with some input parameters. Since I'm not that good with Shell, I prefer the easy way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume you want to run `echo hello` in bash, then

```
    Process process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "bash",
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false
        }
    };
    process.Start();
    await process.StandardInput.WriteLineAsync("echo hello");
    var output = await process.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: But why in bash? What if the shell is zsh? =)

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov `bash` is assumed to be available and preconfigured on most Linux/UNIX machines, while `zsh` isn't there yet.