# ASP.NET Core API to execute bash comands on linux server

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, api, asp.net-core

I am absolutely new to ASP.NET Core.

I want to send a GET-Request to my Linux server which is hosting my ASP.NET Core API to execute some bash commands and return the given output in my GET-Response.

I found a similar question: [ASP.NET Core execute Linux shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987760/asp-net-core-execute-linux-shell-command) but I am not sure if the answer is really the solution for my problem neither how to use this package.

Is there a solution for this like:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TodoItem>>> GetTodoItems()
{
    bashOutput = BASHCOMMAND(whoami);
    return await bashOutput;
}
```

Or is there may a better way to execute commands on my linux server and return the value via API? It doesn't have to be ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Did you try the solution you find on the other link? What issues you are facing there?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have no idea how to use this package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 public static string Run(string cmd, bool sudo = false)
    {
        try
        {
            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "/bin/bash",
                Arguments = (sudo ? "sudo " : "") + "-c '" + cmd + "'",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
            };

            Process proc = new Process() { StartInfo = psi, };
            proc.Start();
            string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            proc.WaitForExit();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The Command '" + psi.Arguments + "' endet with exitcode: " + proc.ExitCode);
                return proc.ExitCode.ToString();
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception exc) 
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Native Linux comand failed: " + cmd);
            Debug.WriteLine(exc.ToString()); 
        }

        return "-1";
    }
```